# Express installed but not in node_modules folder as should be

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build an express app out of my textbook.  I've created the js file and installed express but it's not creating an express module in the node_modules.  When i try to run the node file.js, it gives me:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\express.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?  Thanks for your help.

Tried installing npm install express, npm install --save express, npm install -g express, uninstalling nodejs and reinstalling and repeating.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(function(req, res){ 
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(404);
    res.send('404 - Not Found');

});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.type('text/plain');
    res.status(500);
    res.send('5oo - Server Error');

});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() { 
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; Press Ctrl-C to terminate.');

});
```

After correctly code issues, it should work.  but I'm getting the error message above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the **node_modules** folder and running `npm install` after that?

Just make sure all of your dependencies are in the **package.json** file before you delete the folder and also check if there is **express** module listed inside package.json file.

Comment: I didn't try that before.   thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it and when I tried to run the npm install command, I got:

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'

i checked package.json and it appears that's in there.  Is there anything that could cause this?  Thanks.

Comment: @bsayles15 `semver` is used by npm to parse version numbers. Are you sure you have npm correctly installed?

Comment: I believe so.  The npm install command works in the command prompt.  Is there any way to test this?

Comment: npm@6.9.0 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm.   yeah it looks like it's installed correctly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, whenever I try to install any package, I get a bunch of lines with ERR on them......could this potentially be the problem with modules not installing?  if so, how do I fix this?  Thanks

Comment: @bsayles15 You can try npm --version in the terminal to check if it gets printed, but I would suggest reinstalling the npm.